# How to display Java keystore SecretKeyEntry from command line

Tags: java, command-line, keystore

I have a Java keystore file using the storetype JCEKS. It contains SecretKeyEntry entries. I would like to be able to dump, from the command line, the actual secret keys stored in this file. I tried this:

```
keytool -list -keystore secretkeys.jks -storetype JCEKS
```

which returned

```
Keystore type: JCEKS
Keystore provider: SunJCE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

secret1, May 27, 2016, SecretKeyEntry
```

But that does not show me the key itself. How can I extract and look at, from the command line, the secret key?

Comment: This [SecurityExchange post](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/66865/96204) might help.

Comment: Using the command in the the SecurityExchange post you reference gives me `keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format`. This is even when I add the option `-storetype JCEKS`.

Comment: @Castaglia The linked post is about private key entries (asymmetric keys) while this here is a secret key entry (symmetric key). Small but important difference.

Comment: You can't. `keytool` is designed to prevent extraction of private keys and secret keys. With `keytool`, you can convert your keystore to another type, such as PKCS #12, and try to use another tool, like OpenSSL, to examine the keys themselves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible with keytool.

Converting the keystore to PKCS#12 and then using OpenSSL to view the key doesn't work either, because this is a symmetric key (**SecretKeyEntry**).

If you are stuck with the command line, you could write a small Java program that does it. Something like this:

```
String fileName = "secretkey.ks";
char[] password = "mypassword".toCharArray();
String alias = "secret1";

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
    ks.load(fis, password);
    SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) ks.getKey(alias, password);
    System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, secretKey.getEncoded()).toString(16));
}
```

This prints out the secret key as a hex string (`toString()` with radix 16).

Or you could use the GUI program [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org).